# How to fix daemon reload access dined issue?

Tags: nginx, debian, openresty

"systemctl enable openresty"

**What I get**

Synchronizing state of openresty.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.

Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable openresty

Failed to reload daemon: Access denied

Failed to reload daemon: Access denied

Failed to enable unit: Access denied

**This the the screenshot**

`systemctl status openresty`

openresty.service - The NGINX HTTP and reverse proxy server

Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openresty.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-08-11 17:01:13 UTC; 2h 37min ago

Process: 8875 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Aug 11 17:01:13 instance-2 systemd{1]: Starting The NGINX HTTP and reverse proxy server...

Aug 11 17:01:13 instance-2 systemd[8875]: openresty.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory

Aug 11 17:01:13 instance-2 systemd[8875]: openresty.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/nginx: No such file or directory

Aug 11 17:01:13 instance-2 systemd(1]: openresty.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC

Aug 11 17:01:13 instance-2 systemd(1]: openresty.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Aug 11 17:01:13 instance-2 systemd(1]: Failed to start The NGINX HTTP and reverse proxy server.

[This is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onyBZ.png)

`journalctl -u openresty`

-- Logs begin at Tue 2021-08-10 17:42:07 UTC, end at Wed 2021-08-11 19:20:05 UTC. --

Aug 10 19:14:22 instance-2 systemd(1]: Starting The OpenResty Application Platform...

Aug 10 19:14:22 instance-2 systemd(1]: Started The OpenResty Application Platform.

Aug 10 22:00:10 instance-2 systemd(1]: Stopping The OpenResty Application Platform...

Aug 10 22:00:10 instance-2 systemd(1]: openresty.service: Succeeded.

Aug 10 22:00:10 instance-2 systemd(1]: Stopped The OpenResty Application Platform.

Aug 10 22:00:10 instance-2 systemd(1]: Starting The OpenResty Application Platform...

Aug 10 22:00:10 instance-2 nginx[4012]: nginx: [emerg] directive "server_name" is not terminated by ";" in /etc/openresty/sites-enabled/m.facebook.com.conf:7

Aug 10 22:00:10 instance-2 nginx[4012]: nginx: configuration file /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test failed

Aug 10 22:00:10 instance-2 systemd(1]: openresty.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Aug 10 22:00:10 instance-2 systemd(1]: openresty.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Aug 10 22:00:10 instance-2 systemd(1]: Failed to start The OpenResty Application Platform.

Aug 10 22:01:15 instance-2 systemd(1]: Starting The OpenResty Application Platform...

Aug 10 22:01:15 instance-2 nginx[4034]: nginx: [emerg] directive "server_name" is not terminated by ";" in /etc/openresty/sites-enabled/m.facebook.com.conf:7

Aug 10 22:01:15 instance-2 nginx[4034]: nginx: configuration file /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx. conf test failed

Aug 10 22:01:15 instance-2 systemd(1]: openresty. service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Aug 10 22:01:15 instance-2 systemd(1]: openresty.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Aug 10 22:01:15 instance-2 systemd(1]: Failed to start The OpenResty Application Platform.

Aug 11 17:01:13 instance-2 systemd(1]: Starting The NGINX HTTP and reverse proxy server...

Aug 11 17:01:13 instance-2 systemd[8875]: openresty.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory

Aug 11 17:01:13 instance-2 systemd[8875]: openresty.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning / usr /sbin / nginx : No such file or directory

Aug 11 17:01:13 instance-2 systemd(1]: openresty.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC

Aug 11 17:01:13 instance-2 systemd(1]: openresty.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Aug 11 17:01:13 instance-2 systemd(1]: Failed to start The NGINX HTTP and reverse proxy server.

[This is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STNc2.png)

Comment: Try as root, or with sudo. `sudo systemctl enable openresty`.

Comment: @SYN  ok thank you  can you please also help me in this `sudo systemctl start openresty` Job for openresty.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status openresty.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: Could you edit your initial post, including the output of those `systemctl status openresty` and `journalctl -u openresty` (or `journalctl -xe`)?

Comment: @SYN        done i have editied

Comment: It says `Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/nginx: No such file or directory`. previous logs mention configuration errors ... is nginx still installed? is your nginx configuration valid?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to enable a service, from an account that is not privileged.

You may be able to use sudo, if the system is configured to allow this:

```
sudo systemctl enable openresty
```

If not, you would have to login as root:

```
su
[enter your root password]
systemctl enable openresty
```